# How to refresh the crm form automatically from an iframe aspx page in crm 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm

On my opportunity product form i have added a IFrame to display a asp.net web app. I want to refresh my opportunity product form when i click on a button in asp.net web app. How can i do that ?Its URGENT.
Thanks in advance
Sandeep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this JavaScript on the iframe page and call it.

```
function refreshWindow() {
    if (parent.window.location.href.indexOf("#") == -1) {
        parent.window.location.href = parent.window.location.href + "#";
    }

    parent.window.location.href = parent.window.location.href.replace("#", "");
}
```

Comment: You may also have to add metadata tags to the page that is being refreshed so it doesn't just keep showing a cached version of the page. `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />`